# How can I control Spotify with a multimedia keyboard?

Tags: audio, windows-10, keyboard, spotify, multimedia

Windows 10. Corsair Raptor K50 keyboard.

On my keyboard I have a couple of multimedia keys and a scrollwheel which controls the Windows volume mixer. This controls the overall volume of all the sounds coming from the system. All work as designed.

A master volume control is of limited use given that I'm within arms reach of the volume dial on my speakers. Ideally I'd like to have that scrollwheel re-bound to control the volume on Spotify, without affecting the master volume.

This would save me Alt-Tabbing out of my games to tweak the balance between the game sounds and my music!

Does anyone know a means of achieving this? The Corsair software doesn't seem to have anything to allow this, I haven't spotted any options in Spotify or in Windows and Google doesn't bring me much of use.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you cant do this without third-party app like this one
https://github.com/Cloudzik1337/SpotifyVolumeControler
this app connects to spotify over web api and control volume with keys on your keyboard so for example if u have key to volume up on keyboard rebind it to f8
wich allow you to control only spotify.

Answer (score 0):

You cant controll just your Spotify Player without a third party Application programmed with the Spotify API. But if you have SPotify Premium you can download and install the App for iOS or Android and there you can set your sound with your normal sound buttons or with a tap at the "shared devices?"(on Android a little green speaker under the play button)

Comment: How would an iOS or Android app be useful on a PC?

Comment: He dont want to tab out of the game, so in the mobile app he can controll the Volume of Spotify(not from his PC) so hit wont need to tab out of the game. There is no way(at least i dont know one) to reprogramm the multimedia keys to controll Spotify with his keyboard.